# how to find height of wire from the camera placed at ground using opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, distance, triangulation

How do I find the height of this wire as viewed from the ground w.r.t the camera lens? The wire is parallel to the ground. Triangulation didn't help me out as the width of the wire is too small. Secondly, the width of the wire is again required to calculate the area under ROI by which the code could have calculated the distance. Is there any way in opencv-python to calculate the distance between the camera and the wire? I have an approximate height of 19ft. as the known parameter.[image: wire]

Answer (score 1):

First of all I understood that your camera is not a depth camera so I will make my assumptions according to that.

> The wire is parallel to the ground...

The camera also parallel to the ground and camera is on the ground ?  I assume yes, because you wanna measure the height and the distance wire to camera. Both should be same.

Under these assumptions(because unfortunately question is not really clear, picture neither), you can measure the height if these conditions are required:

- You should make a good ***calibration*** for your camera because you will measure distance by using the pixels which is the units you only have you can use. If you don't calibrate your camera, you never get correct results. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html) is a simple guideline for camera calibration.
- You need a ***reference***. You want to measure that distance but you need a reference for the calculation in the other situations. For instance, if you have a reference like this: in 5 meter height, 1000 pixel length of cable so by using this data; you can make ration for the other states. Without a reference, you can only make assumption. If someone can achieve this then why do we need depth cameras?

Comment: can you please elaborate on the reference idea? Let's assume that we have1000 pixeled cable . How do we proceed further?

Comment: 1- That 1000 pixels length cable should be always in the view, shouldnt be out of view. Because its our reference. 2- 1000 pixel not enough reference, you can also measure that by the program. The reference we need is that the height. If you tell me, this cable now in 800 meter and I measure cable 1000 pixels. This is our reference. If later cable height changes, for example 900 pixel, then we calculate new height with simple ratio problem. Like: new height = (900 x 800)/1000 = 720 meter but of course this is not accurate result for many reasons. This is just an approach.